# How to download Visual Studio Community Edition 2017 (not 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

I installed the new Visual Studio 2019, but it is much slower (at least in my machine) than the 2017 version, and working is getting very frustrating. I want to get back but I can't find where to download the previous version.

I tried using this URL: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/, but it doesn't work. I get the following message "Sorry, we couldn't find any downloads for you."

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. I post the solution in case someone else has the same problem.

You just need to access https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/ and If you get the same message than me, just join to the Visual Studio Dev Essentials (in the same page is a link to do it), it is free, and then you can download older versions of Visual Studio.

Regards,

Comment: Joining the Visual Studio Dev Essentials works, Thanks!

Comment: I found that installing the visual studio installer gives you access to older vs. Under tab 'Available' you can find all version of VS.

Answer (score 71):

The Microsoft site can be induced to give up different versions.

See:
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=15

Change the '15' to 16, and 17 and see what you get.

Answer (score 8):

The URL `https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/` works well for me. I subscribed to the free Visual Studio Dev Essentials and got access to the following versions:

```
2017
2015
2013
2012
2010
```

[image: Screenshot from Aubust 6, 2019]

Comment: did you try to download it? this message shows when trying to download it, past version shows as if they were available, but they don't

Comment: Yes I did at the time and I just did it again. I updated my answer with a screenshot. Is that a downvote by you? Do you mind removing it?

Comment: that's only becuase you join Visual Studio Dev

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue (even with Dev essentials and I didn´t have the option to download vs 2017 community, but 2017 professional instead), then I finally tried downloading the professional version (Then I just cancelled at the moment it asks which components) and suddenly it unlocks the 2017 community install in the visual studio installer hub.

Answer (score 0):

The install launcher you can download from [TechSpot](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6278-visual-studio.html) still works fine.

No strings attached.

Comment: This link currently downloads the 2019 version

Answer (score 0):

As of 27 July 2022 if you have Visual Studio 2019 or 2022 installed you can use the VS installer to download and install in parallel any version of VS 2017.

Comment: Can you say how to do this? When I open the Visual Studio Installer after installing 2019 community, the only options it gives me to install are 2019 Professional and Enterprise. There's no option I can find to download any version of Visual Studio 2017. edit: Downloading an installer using Daniel Poirot's answer worked, and gave me the option to install 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded vs 2019 community edition, i installed the installer and quit the components window, and then downloaded vs 2017 enterprise installer, as the community release is not there, after executing the enterprise installer, the vs 2017 community edition was appeared instead of enterprise and that's it :)